# Error in express and ejs, for displaying data on screen from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying to retrieve data from database and display them on screen(front page ), using express, ejs, and javascript.

Data from database is displayed as a json in console, but after saving in object `myobject` and displaying in console, it displays as a `object myobjectnew[object Object]`,
and passing to ejs page using `module.exports=myobject`;

In ejs file I used

```
w3.getHttpObject("event.js", myFunction);
function myFunction(myobject) 
 w3.displayObject("id01",myobject);

<table id=id01>
<td> fisrtname{{firstname}}</td>
```

but that data is not transfered into ejs file, and output is not displayed, can someone please answer for this question?

Comment: What is `firstname`? Could you create [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Seems that you're missing {} in function

Comment: firstname is the data field inside json file

Answer (score 1):

Cause EJS use another notation, your syntax is for handlebars. For EJS it is:

```
<td> firstname: <%= firstname %></td>
```